# How to make div text fade in

Tags: javascript, function, html

I am using javascript to make text inside a div fade in on page load. It seems to work but most times the text initially shows on page load for about half a second, disappears and then fades in like it's supposed to. I've tried moving the javascript into the header, above body tag and below /body tag. It always runs the same. Thanks.

```
<body onload="javascript:ShowDiv('Layer63');">

<div id="Layer63" class="style1z">
<span class="style16">“Line 1 of fade in text"<br />
“Line 2 of fade in text"</span><br />
-<span class="style12">“Line 3 of fade in text"</span></div>

</body>

<script>
function ShowDiv(name){
//duration of transition (1000 miliseconds equals 1 second)
var duration = 1500;
// how many times should it should be changed in delay duration
var AmountOfActions=30;

var diiv= document.getElementById(name);
diiv.style.opacity = '0';   diiv.style.display = 'block';   var counte=0;
setInterval(function(){counte ++;
   if ( counte<AmountOfActions) { diiv.style.opacity = counte/AmountOfActions;}
},
duration / AmountOfActions);
}
</script>
```

Comment: What explorer are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting these css attributes:

```
#Layer63 {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

Since you're animating opacity from 0 anyway and set ur display to block with js why not have them hidden at pageload?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the **`fadeIn()`** method in [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Layer63").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Or you could pull the code from there, if you want to use pure JavaScript:

http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/